# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, notepad.exe

Tags: c#, консоль

Создаю .txt (по сути) файл и открываю его через Блокнот. При редактировании и попытке сохранения возникает ошибка `Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом`.

Код:

```
try { File.CreateText($"{ver}.bgz"); }
catch { Console.WriteLine("Ошибка открытия файла со списком изменений"); err = true; }

if (!err)
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", $"{ver}.bgz");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы открываете файл, но не закрываете его. Поэтому блокнот не получает доступа.

Попробуйте так:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllText($"{ver}.bgz", "весь ваш текст тут");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка открытия файла со списком изменений");
    err = true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А можно ли как-то пометить процесс блокнота и триггить его закрытие?

Comment: @SoSo: Да. Напишите `Process p = Process.Start(...); p.WaitForExit();`

Comment: @SoSo: Или если хотите асинхронно, то взведите `EnableRaisingEvents` и подпишитесь на `Exited`, как в примере [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Спасибище. (15 симв)

Comment: @SoSo: Рад, что помогло!